# Json Object Array Mapping

Tags: java, json, gson, resttemplate

I have a POJO for mapping json through GSON as below:

```
public class Email {
    private String emailFrom;
    private String[] emailTo;
    private String subject;

    //getters and setters 
}
```

Next I am creating JSON object like this in my client application:

```
JSONObject basicParams = new JSONObject();
basicParams.put("emailFrom", "abc@gmail.com ");

String[] emailnew= {"cde@gmail.com ","fgh@gmail.com"};
basicParams.put("emailTo", emailnew);
basicParams.put("subject", "Test GSON");
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(request.toString(), headers);// converting the json object toString here seems to be the issue
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(testUrl, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
```

And in my controller I am doing this:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
Email email = gson.fromJson(json, Email.class);
```

It's throwing error.
My JSON looks like this when I debug:

```
"basic" -> " {"templateName":"masterTemplate","subject":"Test GSON","emailFrom":"abc@gmail.com","emailTo":"[Ljava.lang.String;@1dc2c13c"}"
```

Why does it has object reference? How can I have it hold actual values?

Comment: What error is it throwing? What doe you mean by "My invoking JSON looks like"? Is the output some debug print?

Comment: Where does the second snippet connect to the third? How are you getting the JSON string? What library is `JSONObject`?

Comment: Error: parser error in line 1..

Comment: I am writing a client too and in that I am creating my JSON object, using Rest Template to invoke my restful web service.

Comment: You're mixing two different libs.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what library you are using.  It appears that you are inputting an array in the value for the key-value pair:

```
basicParams.put("emailTo", emailnew);
```

But you input Strings in the other entries.  Could you please provide a link to the library?

Comment: I am using import org.json.JSONObject; library

Comment: From your link provided, it says this: "The values can be any of these types: Boolean, JSONArray, JSONObject, Number, String, or the JSONObject."  Its type must be able to be converted to one of those objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your first JSON library doesn't know how to handle arrays. It's just calling `toString()` on it. You need to wrap the array into a `List` object:

```
basicParams.put("emailTo", Arrays.asList(emailnew));
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your `JSONObject` is from [JSON in Java](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20160810). There does not seem any problem in my trial. Here is my code:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import org.json.JSONObject;

class Email {
    private String emailFrom;
    private String[] emailTo;
    private String subject;

    public String getEmailFrom() {
        return emailFrom;
    }

    public String[] getEmailTo() {
        return emailTo;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject basicParams = new JSONObject();
        basicParams.put("emailFrom", "abc@gmail.com ");
        String[] emailnew= {"cde@gmail.com ","fgh@gmail.com"};
        basicParams.put("emailTo", emailnew);
        basicParams.put("subject", "Test GSON");

        String json = basicParams.toString();
        System.out.println(json);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Email email = gson.fromJson(json, Email.class);
        System.out.println(email.getEmailFrom());
        for (String emailTo : email.getEmailTo()) {
            System.out.println(emailTo);
        }
        System.out.println(email.getSubject());
    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
{"subject":"Test GSON","emailFrom":"abc@gmail.com ","emailTo":["cde@gmail.com ","fgh@gmail.com"]}
abc@gmail.com 
cde@gmail.com 
fgh@gmail.com
Test GSON
```

which seems perfectly normal. I'm using the latest version of the libraries (JSON in Java, and Gson) downloaded directly from the maven central [here](http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/json/json/20160810/json-20160810.jar) and [here](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/google/code/gson/gson/2.8.0/gson-2.8.0.jar).

So the point is how do you communicate between the client and the server? The communication may be complicated in your case, on contrary to my simple `String json = basicParams.toString();`. I think something is wrong here, making the parsing report error.

Comment: I did the same test and seems to be working.. I think I have found the issue but not sure how to resolve it. Let me update my code.